# I got problem when i update targetSdkVersion 29 to targetSdkVersion 30

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, sdk

**hello all i have problem with my app i update targetSdkVersion from 29   to targetSdkVersion 30 or 31**

and i got problem
app work in all android version 10,9,8,7,etc

in android 11
I have button stop work   to change from activity 1 to activity 2

this java from first java activity

```js
                case 503:
                    if (this.mMainGalleryLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        this.mMainGalleryLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    if (this.mPatternGalleryLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        this.mPatternGalleryLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    if (this.mSeekbarLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        this.mSeekbarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    if (this.mGridLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        this.mGridLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    if (this.mFrameRatiosGalleryLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        this.mFrameRatiosGalleryLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    if (this.mCount < this.mFrameNumber) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill all the images.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    } else if (!this.nextButtonClick) {
                        this.nextButtonClick = true;
                        hideAllAdjustor();
                        disableAllGalleryLayouts();
                        this.mMainFrameLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                        this.mFinalBitmap = this.mMainFrameLayout.getDrawingCache(true);
                        String saveBitmap = saveBitmap("imageforaddingstickerandtext", 100, this.mFinalBitmap);
                        this.mMainFrameLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
                        File file = new File(saveBitmap);
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            OpenShareActivity();

                            Intent Intent = new Intent(this, ShareActivity.class);
                            startActivity(Intent);

                        }

                        return;
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
```

[this 2 pic will explain the problem
when i press the save icon in pic should be move to this activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDpiH.png)

Comment: Does this return true ?   if (file.exists()). Android 30 needs some change around storage. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#scoped-storage

Comment: `else if (!this.nextButtonClick)` That should be: `if (!this.nextButtonClick)`.

Comment: `else {
                        return;
                    }` That should be `return;` You do not need an else if the if returns. It looks ugly all those unneeded elses.

Comment: i remove it and still same problem

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem?

You just said that "in android 11 I have button stop work to change from activity 1 to activity 2"

Does it mean that this code doesn't work? Did you add some debugged log to check the problem point?

```
else if (!this.nextButtonClick) {
                        this.nextButtonClick = true;
                        hideAllAdjustor();
                        disableAllGalleryLayouts();
                        this.mMainFrameLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                        this.mFinalBitmap = this.mMainFrameLayout.getDrawingCache(true);
                        String saveBitmap = saveBitmap("imageforaddingstickerandtext", 100, this.mFinalBitmap);
                        this.mMainFrameLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
                        File file = new File(saveBitmap);
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            OpenShareActivity();

                            Intent Intent = new Intent(this, ShareActivity.class);
                            startActivity(Intent);

                        }

                        return;
                    }
```

Comment: HELLO tancolo I ADD PIC YOU CAN TAKE LOOK TO KNOW WHAT IS THE PROBLEM   THANKS